# Unable to start mysql in JRE6 update 37

Tags: mysql, java, java-5

I have installed `Jre6` update 37 in my product but my `JDK` version is still `1.5.`

Since my product is running as server `JVM` in old versions(i didn't find server folder under `jre/bin`), i just copied Client `jvm.dll` to Server `jvm.dll` and started service. While connecting to `MySql` it throws "`Cannot run program "33366": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`".

Comment: "i just copied Client jvm.dll to Server jvm.dll and started service" - Yeah, don't do that... I'm not surprised it's broken. It's almost *never* a good idea to start fiddling around with binaries like that...

Comment: It seems like an installation problem and as rightly said by Jon, don't copy and paste

Comment: ... and you are surprised it doesn't work... Reminds me when I tried to write DOS .com executables by a text editor, and typing random Alt+ASCII code sequences - and the most response I could get out of it was gibberish on the screen and crazy beeps from the speaker. You esentially did just the same: random input -> random output. (Disclaimer: I was 9 years old, young, feeble, and infinitely optimistic. I was lucky, somehow the file system didn't suffer any damages.).

Comment: @JonSkeet and Sharma, Thanks for your info... I wonder Why there is no server jvm present under JRE/bin in JRE1.6 update 37?

Answer (score 0):

JRE7 breaks some Oracle applications.  You'll need to revert to JRE6

Source:
http://oracleformsinfo.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/frm-92095-oracle-jinitiator-version-too-low-disable-jre-1-7-auto-update-for-all-e-business-suite-and-oracle-forms-end-users/

Comment: I just realized this doesn't really address your question.  Sorry about that!  Hope someone else finds it useful.